# How to check if user installs a mobile app within a web page?

Tags: ios, mobile, web

I know this is possible because today I browsed a mobile web page that said I have installed their native app, and prompted me to read their content in the app. (I haven't logged in, so they must have used some native checking mechanism.)

I know the web page can call out a native app by loading a custom url scheme like 'myapp://some/path', but how does it check if the url scheme exists before loading it? I want to do the same thing with my web app.

And I was seeing this on iOS, is this possible in Android, too?

Comment: This isn't simple and you have to do some hacks to really detect the app existence. Not native because of privacy reasons. First have a look at iOS smart banners to know if this is sufficient for you : http://smartappbanners.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native checking mechanism is called [Smart Banner](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html).  Apple added it to MobileSafari in iOS 6 and higher.

You add the following to your web page:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

Comment: But be aware that the webpage (JS, PHP, ...) cannot know if the app is installed. iOS will do this for you and not give you the info

Comment: It is a banner on top of the page. So I guess this is how they did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The custom URL scheme is the way to go.

They probably delivered a transparent image by that custom URL, and checked if their image delivery mechanism was hit.

So in essence:

- You download page
- The page prompts your browser to hit their "checking service" (image with custom URL scheme?)
- The page checks if the call to the checking service succeeded. If so, it prompts you to use the native app